# How to make internal synchronous post request in Play framework and scala?

Tags: scala, post, playframework

I'm new to Play and Scala. I'm trying to build an Application using Play and Scala. I need to make post call internally to get data from my server. But this should be synchronous. After getting the data from this post request, I need to send that data to front end. I've seen many resources but all are asynchronous. Please help me.

I'm fetching data from **DB** and then should return the data as response.

**DB is at remote server not in the hosted server.**

Comment: Play's actions are asynchronous by default and design. Why would you want to synchronize? And what exactly do you mean with 'send to front end'? A Future[JsValue] can be perfectly used within an action and will be 'sent' to the client once available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not block anyway.

```
def action = Action.async {
  WS.url("some url")
    .post(Json.toJson(Map("query"->query)))
    .map { response => 
      val jsonResponse = response.json
      // in this place you have your response from your call
      // now just do whatever you need to do with it,
      // in this example I will return it as `Ok` result
      Ok(jsonResponse)
    }
}
```

Just map the result of your call and modify it staying in context of `Future` and use `Action.async` that takes a `Future`.

If you really want to block use `Await.result(future, 5 seconds)`, importing

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await
```

[See docs for Await here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await$)

Answer (score 0):

All requests are asynchronous but nothing prevents you from waiting the response with `await` in your code.

```
val response = await(yourFutureRequest).body
```

The line written above will block until the future has finished.

Comment: val future:Future[JsValue] = WS.url("some url").post(Json.toJson(Map("query"->query))).map{ response=> response.json}

Your suggestion did not work. I got Application does not take parameters